# Setting up a video game title when uploading a gaming video through Youtube API v3 with video_category_id = "20" (Category ID for Video Games)

Tags: youtube, title

I'm using YouTube API v3 to upload gaming videos to my YouTube channel.
I set `video_category_id = "20"  # Category ID for Video Games`.

I would like to set the video game title but can't seem to find a supported parameter in the API documentation that would allow me to do so.

Has anyone been able to set the video game title when using YouTube API v3?

If it is not yet implemented, can anyone suggest a workaround?